# Marketing Cloud FTP Use

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

Regarding the use of the upload FTP Marketing Cloud, **Where can I find the userid and password to access "Enhanced FTP"** with a third-party client ( filezilla ) ?

The only information at our disposal is my FTP address to be included as `hostname : ftp.s7.exacttarget.com`

The guide is written :

> You use a special user ID and password to access the folder . This is
>   not the same user ID and password That You use to log into the
>   Salesforce Marketing Cloud application

Also if I try to use an external address in the file location (External FTP Site) , the import returns me the error :

> The import instance could not be validated for the Following reason (
>   s ) : unexpectedError

That's a very generic as error and therefore difficult to understand the cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot find the **emails that were sent providing you with the User/Pass when this service was activated**, you will need to contact the general support desk or your account representative and have them resend you the FTP username and password.

Keep in mind that you will need to have this ability activated on your account to access it(usually through Automation Studio). It does not come standard.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to check the existence of this message. If not, ask the service activation. I just news, I advice